# Are decision trees in SPSS classification or clustering trees?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, spss, cart

I have a dataset consisting of 140 features (categorical and continuous variables) and one dependent variable (continuous). I used SPSS classify function without setting any classes, using CHAID growth method and I got my trees. I cannot understand if this is a classification problem or clustering problem since I did not set predefined classes.
[image: the tree I got]

If it is a classification problem, based on what value can I cluster my data?

Comment: Decision trees are classification (or regression) trees. You probably noticed that it requires dependent variable. It is a superviced procedure.

Comment: Thank you, so if it does not require a dependent variable does that make it a clustering technique? Because spss let's you "not" choose a dependent variable but an influence variable

Comment: If the dependent variable is categorical, that will be a classification tree. If it is scale, that will be a regression tree.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already mentioned, decision trees are classifiers (or regressors), and they can not perform clustering.
This is confirmed by [SPSS manual](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsd/nodes/chaid.html?context=cpdaas) that confirms that the algorithm you are using is indeed a classifier:

> CHAID, or Chi-squared Automatic Interaction Detection, is a **classification** method for building decision trees by using chi-square statistics to identify optimal splits.